# Reading displayed pixels on the screen

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx, glreadpixels

I want to read pixels from the screen/monitor ***after*** the image has been displayed to the user.

MS provides `Graphics.CopyFromScreen` which [apparently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> Performs a bit-block transfer of color data from the screen to the
>   drawing surface of the Graphics.

But is this really true? Does it not read the pixels from the frame buffer?

`glReadPixels` ([doc](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml)) reads from the frame buffer - is that before or after the screen has been updated (it doesn't specify)?

Would the "MS" equivalent to `glReadPixels` be to use DirectX's `GetBuffer`? (such as the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32740246/596841))

Comment: Using OpenGL (with context and other stuff) `glReadPixels` reads from the buffer bound to `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER`. It happens that the shown window is also bound for reading. So you read pixels after the image is displayed.

Comment: How do you present the content on the screen? Rendered with OpenGL -> use glReadPixels. Rendered with DirectX -> use directx method. Other method -> depends on which method you are using.